# swfupload - multiple instances and setting dynamic data with setPostParam

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, swfupload

I am using swfupload, and have a bunch of 'Attach File' links and each one of them opens up the same Jquery Dialog which is associated with 1 swfupload instance. I tried to set custom post params but it fails:
www.arianhojat.com/temp/code/swfupload/index.html

if you remove the 'setPostParam' line its fine but id like to set params... It gives an error in firebug: "uncaught exception: Call to SetPostParams failed"...

So instead i tried an alternate solution... I came up with recreating the swfupload object each time the Dialog opens up... and destroy it after it closes... but i get a "uncaught exception: Could not find Flash element" at the end. not sure if that is a critical error as the popup still shows up if you reclick links. I think this may be possiblly the way to go but not sure about that error

Here is my online example of that code in action:
http://www.arianhojat.com/temp/code/swfupload/index_destroy.html

(PS the file upload should close the dialog and alert an error, as I dont have that host setup right now to correspond to the java servlet backend i have to handle it... just wanted to get the frontend working first and get rid of that error so errors are first handled gracefully without firebug user like myself noticing a js error occured.)

Comment: It seems to work fine for me, I'm in Chrome on OSX, what environment are you in?

Comment: curious which one works fine?, I'm interested in getting the 2nd one to work as the 1st one doesnt seem to even get close to uploading ... 2nd one outputs an error in FireBug ... Firefox 3.5.11 on Windows XP.

Comment: i figured out having a Dialog/popup that gets hidden causes problems with the flash/swfupload... here is my solution using positioning to close the popup:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355135/how-to-re-assign-jqueryui-dialog-close-button-event

Comment: and here is a full example:

http://www.arianhojat.com/temp/code/swfupload/solution.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use css positioning to hide (and not display:block/none;) and show your dialog as the Flash reloads when you hide/unhide it and goofs.

Comment: example here if still up:
http://www.arianhojat.com/temp/code/swfupload/solution.html